# How to fit model with individual measurement error in DiceKriging, or can it?

Tags: r, stochastic, kriging

I have a set of 5 data points (`x=10,20,30,40,50` and its corresponding response values `y` and `noise` as s.d. of `y`). These data are obtained from stochastic computer experiments.

**How can I use DiceKriging in R to fit a kriging model for these data?**

```
x <- seq(from=10, to=50, length=5)
y <- c(-0.071476,0.17683,0.19758,0.2642,0.4962)
noise <- c(0.009725,0.01432,0.03284, 0.1038, 0.1887)
```

Examples online with heterogeneous noise are pre-specified with `coef.var`, `coef.trend` and `coef.theta`. It is unlikely that I can have *a priori* on these.

I have referred to the answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/162052/kriging-with-individual-errors). However, other references suggest adding the nugget parameter lambda is similar to adding homogeneous noise, which is not likely "individual errors".

Comment: Is that really noise if it is so correlated with x and y? I may not understand heterogeneous noise completely. If not, perhaps add the noise as an independent effect in the model?

Comment: @cgage I have changed the wordings in case I used the wrong word to make myself clear. Yes, these data are highly linearly correlated (just to test, the actual data are much more nonlinear). But being able to tell the model "there are individual errors" but not same sd for everyone" makes it a better estimation of confidence intervals (and thus EI, expected improvements).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of `km` with noise is quite simple:

```
model <- km(~1, data.frame(x=x), y, noise.var = noise, covtype = "matern3_2")
```

However, your noise term make the line search part of L-BFGS algorithm fail. It may be due to the fact that is is strongly correlated with `y`, because when I run the following lines, it works:

```
noice <- c(0.009725,0.01432,0.03284, 0.001, 0.1887)
model <- km(~1, data.frame(x=x), y, noise.var = noise, covtype = "matern3_2")
```

Comment: I have been waiting for your answer! Thanks.